# how to get specific dot between number

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to delete dot only in between numbers

I have text `"dolar. 2.000.000"`

I have tried using `\\.\d*?`, but `.` in dollar also deleted

I want it displayed as `"dolar. 2000000"`.

Comment: I think you mean "digits", not "numbers", in your first sentence. We know what you mean but it's always best to be precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use positive [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
"dolar. 2.000.000".gsub(/(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)/, '')
#⇒ "dolar. 2000000"
```

`(?<=\d)` here means “preceded by not included in the match digit” and `(?=\d)` means “followed by not included in the match digit.”

Comment: not completly works, its only delete first . between digit, result displays is dolar. 2000.000

Comment: No way. You have an induced error. Copy-paste the snippet above and make sure it perfectly works.

Comment: sorry, I miss something, yes, this is the simple one and correct

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more ways to do that.

```
str = "dolar. 2.000.000"
```

All of the following return `"dolar. 2000000"`.

```
str.gsub(/\d\.\d/) { |s| s.delete('.') }

str.gsub(/(\d)\.(\d)/, '\1\2')

h = Hash.new { |_,k| k.delete('.') } #=> {} 
str.gsub(/\d\.\d/, h)
```

In #3 `h[k]` returns `k.delete('.')` if the hash has no key `k`. Since the hash has no keys that will be returned for all matches.

Comment:  `Hash.new { |_,k| k.delete('.') }` ❤❤❤